# Which tools is used to draw this image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, tools

I am new in Photoshop CS6. I have a sample picture and i want to draw a picture same like this

[image] I dont know how many tools are used to draw this. Please suggest me which tools are used to draw like this image?

Comment: It likely wasn't drawn in Photoshop but in a vector illustration program such as Adobe Illustrator. You *could* do his in Photoshop but it'd be much easier in Illustrator. As to 'what tools' that's simply too broad of a question. *Lots* of tools were likely used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was going to write this as a comment, but it got a bit too long. This is something that I'm always thinking when I see questions like this. Don't ask broad questions like this. Analyze the image and divide it into smaller tasks/questions.

---

---

Rather than start with: "How can I make this {complex-example}?", start by breaking it down into specifics.

**Breaking it down:**

- There are 7 photos forming a circle.
- They are divided by 7 lines or each photo object has a gap inbetween
- To be efficient, I could probably:

  - Make a circle shape...
  - Cut a hole in the middle to create a ring shape
  - Divide that into 7 shapes using 7 lines.
- At this point I would need to place the photos within each shape.
- Once that is done, I need to make a curving arrow.
- Now I need to write a curved text on top of that that arrow.

**This way you got it divided into small tasks and searchable chunks:**

<sup><sub>Note that I'm using keywords, rather than full sentences, not that it matters much. Google knows either way.</sub></sup>

- For making the ring: `"Illustrator shape cut out"`
- Dividing the ring into 7 shapes: `"Illustrator divide shape"` or `"Illustrator cut shape with stroke"`
- Placing the photos into the shapes: `"Illustrator place photo inside shape"`
- Creating a curved arrow: `"Illustrator curved arrow"`
- Curved text on top of the arrow: `"Illustrator curve text"`

You don't need to analyze the whole image immediately. You can start with the basics. Drill deep enough to get a starting point and then work your way forward from that. Each time you find yourself stuck, google the problem.